# Whats the difference between kono/kore, sono/sore, ano/are, dono/dore in simple terms?

Tags: word-choice, words, usage, nuances

Am learning Japanese and I can't decide when to appropriately use either of the pairs:  **kono/kore**, **sono/sore**, **ano/are**, **dono/dore**

Can someone please explain with Examples how these can be used in what scenario or why woull one use `kono` and not use `kore` and in what occasion.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is simple:  これ・それ・あれ・どれ are abstract this/that/that one/which one.  この・その・あの・どの need a specific object to modify; that is, something must come after it.

> この本　➝　This book
>   その本　➝　That book
>   あの本　➝　That book (over there)
>   どの本　➝　Which book

In fact, I believe この・その・あの・どの are just contractions of これ・それ・あれ・どれ ＋ の.

Comment: To tweak the wording somewhat for better correspondence with English concepts, the words ending in れ can be treated like nouns (they can be used on their own as subjects, objects, etc.), while the words ending in の can be treated like adjectives (they **must** be followed by a noun or noun phrase, and cannot be used on their own).  Also, FWIW, the modern の terms did not derive as contractions: the root forms こ・そ・あ were the original forms in the _Kojiki_ and _Man'yōshū_, to which の was added as a particle (or even other particles like は or を).  The れ forms are the innovation, appearing later.

Answer (score 0):

これ、それ and あれ are used as pronouns, while この、その and あの are used as demonstrative determiners.

```
これは私のカバンです —> This is my bag
このカバンは青いです —> This bag is blue
```